# PyInstaller exe marked as virus

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, google-chrome, pyinstaller

I just run this command `python -m PyInstaller --onefile .\main.py`.
The file was saved in the dist folder.
I uploaded the file on github as [release](https://github.com/arnavnagpurkar/Cricket-Game/releases/tag/cricketgame1.0) for my [project](https://github.com/arnavnagpurkar/Cricket-Game/).
To verify I clicked on download and when tried to run the file and my chrome marked the file as virus.
[Google chrome marked file as virus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXyCL.png)

Then I tried to open the file by double clicking(in file explorer windows) and my windows also marked the file as virus and deleted it.

If this happens how can I deliver projects to my future clients as an executable file??

Can anyone fix this issue???

Comment: Wait. In my experience very new pyinstaller versions may give false positives to antiviruses. But within few weeks antivirus will detect it correctly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using onefile mode can lead to some anti virus programs picking it up as a false positive, this is a known issue with PyInstaller.

Either, create an exception within your antivirus app to stop detection, or build the file without onefile mode. You could also submit your file to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission, and hopefully stop your file being detected in the future.